# Randomize Text File to Avoid Unbalanced Tree

Tags: java, file-io, binary-search-tree

Currently, I have a list of movies that I am reading in from a text file. Here is an example:

```
Forrest Gump/1994/PG-13/142/8.8/Tom Hanks
Star Wars/1977/PG/121/8.7/Mark Hamill,Carrie Fisher,Harrison Ford
Jaws/1975/PG/124/8.1/
```

I was told that I should randomize the text before adding it to the Binary Search Tree to avoid having an unbalanced tree, which is what I am trying to accomplish. I have no issue reading the file I just need help figuring out how I can randomize the text. My initial thought was to store it into and `ArrayList` and then populate it randomly but i can't quite think of the implementation.
Here is where I read from the text file:

```
try{
        Scanner read = new Scanner( new File("movies.txt") );
        do{
            ArrayList<String> actorList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = read.nextLine();
            String [] tokens = line.split("/");
            if ( tokens.length == 6 ){
                actorList.addAll( Arrays.asList( tokens[5].split(",") ) );
            }
            // BEFORE ADDING TO TREE I WANT TO RANDOMIZE HERE
            tree.add( new Movie(tokens[0], Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]), tokens[2], Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]), 
                    Double.parseDouble(tokens[4]), actorList ));
        }while( read.hasNext() );
        read.close();
    }catch( FileNotFoundException fnf ){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
```

BST Class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
/**
 * The head of the tree.
 */
private Node root;

/**
 * Constructor that declares the head of tree to null.
 */
public BinarySearchTree() {
    root = null;
}
/**
 * Returns null if head of tree is empty.
 * @return null if head of tree is empty.
 */
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return root == null;
}
/**
 * Adds a Movie to the tree.
 * @param w The Movie object to be added.
 */
public void add( Movie m ){
    root = add( m,root );
}
/**
 * Helper function for adding a Movie to the search tree.
 * @param w The Movie to be added.
 * @param tree The root of the binary search tree.
 * @return The tree with the added values.
 */
private Node add( Movie m, Node tree ){
    if( tree == null ){
        return new Node(m);
    }else{
        if ( m.compareTo( tree.getData() ) <= 0 ){
            tree.setLeft( add( m, tree.getLeft() ));
        }else{
            tree.setRight( add( m, tree.getRight() ));
        }
        return tree;
    }
}
/**
 * Searches the tree recursively for a Movie object.
 * @param w The Movie object to search for.
 * @return Null if the Movie does not exist or the searched Movie if found.
 */
public Node search( Movie m ){
    if ( root == null ){
        System.out.println("No items to search.");
        return null;
    }else{
        return search( m, root );
    }
}
/**
 * Helper function for searching the tree for a Movie object.
 * @param w The Movie object to search for.
 * @param n The root of the search tree.
 * @return The Movie object if the searched Movie exists in the tree.
 */
private Node search( Movie m, Node n ){
    if ( m.compareTo( n.getData() ) == 0 ){
        if( n.getLeft() != null ){
           Node node = search(m, n.getLeft());
           if( node != null ){
               return node;
           }
        }
        return n;
    }
    if ( m.compareTo( n.getData() ) < 0 ){
        if( n.getLeft() == null ){
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
            return null;
        }else{
            return search(m, n.getLeft());
        }
    }else{
        if ( n.getRight() == null ){
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
            return null;
        }else{
            return search(m, n.getRight());
        }
    }
}
```

Issue Searching Movie by Rating:

```
    System.out.println("Select a rating: ");
    System.out.println("1. G");
    System.out.println("2. PG");
    System.out.println("3. PG-13");
    System.out.println("4. R");
    switch ( checkForMenu(1,4) ){

    case 1: rating = "G";
            break;
    case 2: rating = "PG";
            break;
    case 3: rating = "PG-13";
            break;
    case 4: rating = "R";
            break;
    }
    Movie temp = new Movie( "Unknown", 0, rating, 0, 0.0, null );
    Node leftMost = tree.search(temp);
    if( leftMost != null ){
           while(leftMost != null && temp.compareTo( leftMost.getData() ) == 0){
                System.out.println(leftMost.getData());
                leftMost = leftMost.getRight();
           }
    }
```

Comment: How randomizing will help you in avoiding unbalanced BST? May be a silly question but please answer.

Comment: better make your tree self-balancing. If you use Java SE `TreeSet` or `TreeMap` as basis, it is already self-balancing.

Comment: Why dont you use `AVL` or `RedBlackTree`. Actually Java internally uses `RedBlackTree` itself.

Comment: @JCCS shuffling or randomizing the data will not help you. You need to understand your problem first. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Please tell me which class is `tree` instance of? If you have used your own class then may be I can help you with code for AVL or RedBlackTree.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Maybe I am misunderstanding what I was told, but anyways I added my BST class

Comment: For sure OP's tree is not self-balancing.

Comment: @JCCS You can never get completely(perfectly) balanced tree using standard `BST` whatever randomization you use. You need to write self-balancing tree for example `AVLTree`.

Comment: @akhil_mittal I understand that there are self-balancing trees, but for this purpose I am required to use my own created tree. Does it look like my `BST` has any potential balancing problems?

Comment: The problem in not with your implementation as such, regular `BST` is not self-balanced and will result into skewed tree quite often. If you want to achieve a perfectly balanced tree then you should self-balanced `BST` e.g. `AVLTree` or `RedBlackTree`.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Oh, i did not know regular BST resulted skewed often I thought it was always balanced thanks for clarifying. Now, the reason I originally asked this question was because of a problem I have when finding a movie by searching a rating. If you are able maybe you can help me out and see what is wrong with the code i posted as right now I only get 1 or 2 of the movies with that rating not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

To "randomize" your `List`, use `Collections.shuffle()`:

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
do {    
    //...                         // populate `movies`
    movies.add(new Movie(....)); 
} while (read.hasNext());

Collections.shuffle(movies);      // shuffle
for (Movie m : movies) {          // populate the tree
   tree.add(m);
}
```

This will not make your tree completely balanced, but at least will except the situation when the tree becomes a linked list in case of ordered initial data set.

Comment: Will this help in keeping BST unbalanced?

Comment: @akhil_mittal if OP's `tree` is not self-balancing, shuffling won't make it fully balanced, but at least it will avoid the tree becoming a linked list if initial dataset is sorted.

Comment: Yes but there are still chances that it will be skewed.

Comment: @akhil_mittal for sure. I'm not talking about full and proper balancing.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Thanks the intentions of shuffling was to make sure to completely avoid getting a `LinkedList` type tree. Now I know this is a different question but originally the reason I thought my tree was unbalanced because of an issue I was having with the code I just posted, where I am searching for a movie by its rating. I would appreciate if you can look over that and my `search` in `BST` to see why I don't get the output of all the movies when I search by rating. But, thanks this was what I was looking for.

Comment: @JCCS In your case search for movies with exact rating would require full traversal, because tree is ordered by movie natural order, not rating.

Comment: @JCCS Sorry for so many questions,  but im really confused how would I implement full traversal, I am sure nothing is wrong with my `search` in `BST`?

Comment: @JCCS well, `search()` now lookups for *particular* movie which *fully equals* (`compareTo = 0`) to what you pass as argument. Not for rating! To search by rating you can either: 1) make `Map<Rating, List<Movie>>` where you'll put movies by rating; 2) perform full traversal of your BST to collect movies with particular rating.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** OP has asked for searching all the movies which has specific rating and it may help him. As per his comment `I would appreciate if you can look over that and my search in BST to see why I don't get the output of all the movies when I search by rating.`

As it seems your tree is using name of the movie as key and you want to search based on rating, you need to treaverse the complete tree. But this would have defeated the purpose of logarithmic search capability we get with `BST`. The complete search can be written like:

```
private Movie searchBasedOnRating(String rating, Node currentNode)
{  
    Node result = null
    if (currentNode == null)
        return null;
    Movie movie = (Movie) currentNode.getData();
    if (movie.getRating().equals(rating)) 
        return movie ;
    if (currentNode.getLeft() != null)
        result = searchBasedOnRating(rating,currentNode.getLeft());
    if (result == null)
        result = searchBasedOnRating(rating,currentNode.getRight());
    return result;
}
```

You can modify it as per your requirement but it should give you an idea on a high level. You need to start with `root` node to search with complete tree.

Comment: I'd return `List<Movie>`

Comment: The objective is to provide an idea to OP how to search a movie based on rating. The code can be modified by OP to suit the requirements.